# Detecting if a certain text is JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, nlp

I have a text file. Its content may be plain text or JavaScript source code. I need an efficient and high accuracy approach to detect if the text file contains plain text or JavaScript code.

**My approach**:
I tried to extract syntax-specific keywords, punctuations, operators, regex based loop detection for this. I added all the values and divided it by the length of the file and got a specific ratio. Let's say the ratio is greater than 0.2 then the file is JavaScript else plain text. The problem I ran in was with regex based loop detection. It was taking too much time for file size > 1 Mega Bytes, hence I abandoned the approach.

Any resources or approaches would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is a very high level idea. you could go with nlp approach (machine learning). Train a model on bunch of javascript statements/documents and also on normal text.

Comment: Yes, that is my backup option. But the thing is there are a lot of memory constraints on my application. I was looking for a more static approach. But thanks for the suggestion anyway @QuantumDreamer

Comment: Assuming that the javascript code doesn't have any errors at all, I would try and run the code under a bunch of programming languages and only the javascript one would come out error free. But this could have many loopholes and would take a long time... just a thought

Comment: Any particular reason to use nlp? Javacsript is _not_ a Natural Language, so there's better options. e.g. It's a well defined grammar, so why not just put it through a Javascript parser?

Comment: I considered that too, but the JavaScript I'm working on is actually malwares. Executing it would have some problems on my local PC. I'll have to execute it in special sandbox env, but that would be a lot of overhead.

Comment: I think you can do some lexical analysing and parsing to determine if it is a valid js code. Some tools like [acron](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn) may meet your requirements.

Comment: @Sinkingpoint any links or resources to know more about the parser?

Comment: @Stephen.W thanks. I think that was what I was looking for.

Comment: @Esh There are some well-known js parser, e.g. esprima, acron. you can simply type `js parser` in google's searchbox and will get lots of result you want.

Comment: @Esh It may take a while to complete the parsing using a complete parse, in case your code's long and complicated. Here my rough idea that you can write an custom parser that can identify some identical JavaScript grammars, i.e., `const` and `let` expression, `var` keywords, arrow functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use NLP in a slightly different manner — read the entire js file, tokenize it and build a frequency table of tokens; use this data to apply the logic you have outlined. I have tried to do this using [wink-nlp](https://github.com/winkjs/wink-nlp) on a **6.6MB JS file** and it produced the frequency table in about **5** seconds on an intel 2.2GHz i7 macbook pro. Here is the Node.js code for your reference:

```
const fs = require( 'fs' );
const winkNLP = require( 'wink-nlp' );
const model = require( 'wink-eng-lite-web-model' );
const its = require( 'wink-nlp/src/its.js' );
const as = require( 'wink-nlp/src/as.js' );

const rawJS = fs.readFileSync( '<your-js-file-with-path>', 'utf8' );

const nlp = winkNLP( model );

const doc = nlp.readDoc( rawJS );
// The const ft has the frequency table:
const ft = doc.tokens().out( its.normal, as.freqTable );
```

Here is the partial output:

```
[ '\n', 160960 ],
[ '.', 125520 ],
[ '(', 108440 ],
[ '/', 106480 ],
[ '=', 95040 ],
[ ')', 74800 ],
[ ';', 64120 ],
.
.
[ '{', 16640 ],
[ '}', 16640 ],
[ 'const', 15920 ],
.
.
```

Comment: Note: the JS file used was an uncompressed one.